# PHP XML Parsing to extract specific value

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to figure out how to get a specific value from the XML

Code :-

```
function getUrlContent($url,$xml_get_subscriber_info){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_get_subscriber_info);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
//return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? $data : false;
return $data;

$a = simplexml_load_string(getURLContent($url,$xml_get_subscriber_info));
```

The XML :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ><SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:root>
        <msg_head>
            <time>2020-08-20 17:57:29</time>
            <from />
            <to />
            <msg_type />
            <serial />
        </msg_head>
        <interface_msg>
            <msg_response>
                <ResponseClass Name="Response">
                    <GetUserClass Name="AJAX">
                        <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
                        <ResultDescr>success</ResultDescr>
                        <IBAN>1</IBAN>
                        <PACKAGEID>208$268$269$345$481$482$619$653$656$663$665$702$764$768$1128$1130$1143$1156$1166</PACKAGEID>
                        <USRSTATUS>1</USRSTATUS>
                        <PREFERNOTIFYMETHOD>1</PREFERNOTIFYMETHOD>
                    </GetUserClass>
                </ResponseClass>
            </msg_response>
        </interface_msg>
    </ns2:root>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to get the packageID payload but i've tried all sort even using `loadXML` function but sometimes i have parser issue using the `loadXML` due to high load but now i've decided to change to `simple_load_xml`.

I've tried the following method :-

```
print_r($xml->children("SOAP-ENV", true)->children("ns2", true));
```

Even tried to cast it as a namespace , no luck

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result,"SimpleXMLElement", 0, "SOAP-ENV", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**`DOMDocument()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/de/domxpath.query.php) instead:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($your_file_as_string);


$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query("//PACKAGEID/text()")  as $package) {
    print_r($package->textContent);
}
?>
```

This yields

```
208$268$269$345$481$482$619$653$656$663$665$702$764$768$1128$1130$1143$1156$1166
```

Comment: Thanks @Jan for the feedback, instead of file as string can a curl response be used?

Comment: Also , this looks similar to what i've done .
$result_provisioning = $result;
$doc = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
$doc->loadXML($result_provisioning);
$resultCode = $doc->getElementsByTagName('PackageID')->item(0)->nodeValue;

But mine uses getElementBytagName and i'll hit the parser issue when i go above 50 tps

Comment: @FreedomPride: You did not specify this code in your question. And yes, a curl response can be used as long as it is a string.

Comment: I had to scrape the following code method because of the issue , but i'm trying your code.. After 50 tps, i'm observing intermittent error : DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in test.php